# Como utilizar preg_replace e preg_match juntos

Tags: php, preg-match, preg-replace

Como faço para usar um `preg_replace` após encontrar uma palavra ou pontuação?

Por exemplo:

Queria que a string: `"Esta conta tem senha: 123456"` retornasse `"Esta conta tem senha: ******"`.

Estou fazendo assim, não está dando erro, porém não dá retorno:

```
<?php
$string = "Esta conta tem senha: 12345.";
function esconde_senha($string)
{
return (preg_match("/^senha$/+", preg_replace("/[A-Za-z0-9]/+", "*", $string)));
}
```

Comment: Primeiramente, tem uma coisa que está confusa: na descrição você diz que a string é `Esta conta tem senha: 123456` mas no código é `Esta conta tem senha: 12345.` (no final tem um ponto em vez do `6`). O ponto faz parte da senha? Como vc usou `[A-Za-z0-9]`, entendo que a senha só deve ter letras e números, é isso ou pode ter outros caracteres? A frase sempre terá o texto `"senha: "` antes da senha? Vai terminar com ponto ou não? Dependendo dessas respostas, a regex pode mudar bastante (ou não, depende de cada caso). Poderia [edit] a pergunta e adicionar esses detalhes?

Answer (score 0):

O código abaixo apresenta um exemplo de como você pode obter esse resultado.

Primeiramente, é importante ressaltar que ele confia no formato da frase desejada:

> Esta conta tem senha: **[senha]**.

Com essa frase, ele procura tudo o que tem entre os dois pontos (`:`) e o ponto final (`.`), utilizando a expressão regular: `/:\s(.*)[.]/`

Que pode ser decomposta como:

| Delimitador da ER | Caracter (:) | Espaço em Branco | Grupo | Ponto final | Delimitador de ER |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| / | : | \s | (.+) | [.] | / |

Onde:

- [Delimitadores](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) são requeridos pelas funções de Expressão Regular:
- `:` aqui é literalmente o caractere (dois pontos) esperado na frase.
- `\s` : Representa qualquer espaço em branco
- `(.+)` : Grupo: é marcado pelos parêntesis e permite-se referenciar posteriormente o conjunto que foi 'casado' pela ER. Neste caso, o `.` representa qualquer caractere sendo modificado pelo `+`, que exige **no mínimo** 1.
- `.` aqui é literalmente o ponto-final da frase.
- Outro delimitador.

```php
$string = "Esta conta tem senha: abc.";
function esconde_senha($string)
{
    preg_match("/:\s(.+)[.]/", $string, $matches);
    $substituir = $matches[1];
    $asteriscos = str_pad(' ', strlen($substituir)+1, '*') . ".";
    $retorno = preg_replace('/:\s(.+)[.]/', $asteriscos, $string);
    return $retorno;
}

echo esconde_senha($string); //retorna: Esta conta tem senha ***.
```

Após encontrar, é necessário saber quantos `*` são necessários para substituir, por isso a função `str_len`. Esse valor é utilizado na função `str_pad` para criar uma string contendo a substituição.

Como a `preg_match` substitui todas as ocorrências e como a ER captura tudo entre `:` e `.`, é necessário recolocar o espaço ( ) e o ponto (`.`).

Você pode testar esse código em: [Exemplo 1](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c001e3198a70381307b39e0db457008b3b84e3b0).
E pode testar a ER em: [Testador de ER](https://www.phpliveregex.com/p/BRh).